# How do I write a character to standard output in C without using stdio.h or any other library header files?

Tags: c, macos

`putchar(char)` writes a character to standard output and is normally provided by `stdio.h`.

How do I write a character to standard output *without* using `stdio.h` or any other standard library file (that is: *no* `#include`:s allowed)?

Or phrased different, how do I implement my own `putchar(char)` with zero `#include` statements?

This is what I want to achieve:

```
/* NOTE: No #include:s allowed! :-) */ 

void putchar(char c) {
  /*
   * Correct answer to this question == Code that implements putchar(char).
   * Please note: no #include:s allowed. Not even a single one :-)
   */
}

int main() {
  putchar('H');
  putchar('i');
  putchar('!');
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Clarifications:

- Please note: No `#include`:s allowed. Not even a single one :-)
- The solution does *not* have to be portable (inline assembler is hence OK), but it must compile with gcc under MacOS X.

Definition of correct answer:

- A working `putchar(char c)` function. Nothing more, nothing less :-)

Comment: Short answer: you can't. C was designed to have no on-board I/O. All I/O should be implemented in libraries (since I/O is inherently  platform specific) The standard library *is* a part of the C standard, its implementation is not.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth To learn.

Comment: Copy and paste `stdio.h` and all the headers it includes into the top of your program.  Problem solved.

Comment: @Nemo lol, I guess that's one way to do it...

Comment: @Nemo What would be learnt from that?

Comment: @knorv: What would be learned is how to write `putchar` without including any header files.  (It will be a very platform-dependent answer.  Which is true for any answer to your question.)

Comment: How about getting an inline assembler code, that handles the printing ?

Comment: @Nemo I can only assume that the reason the OP doesn't want to use standard library include files is because s/he doesn't want to link against the library either, so this doesn't help.

Comment: @Nemo Feel free to provide the answer if you think you know it :-)

Comment: @Nemo this is, to be honest, of fairly minimal learning value.  The implementation of `putchar()` will set up the registers for a sys-call - probably to `write()` using `stdout` as the `fd`.    There aren't many times you need to make sys-calls directly.

Comment: @Marko: Actually putchar() will manipulate the stdout `FILE *` buffer.  It usually does this directly with knowledge of the internals (for speed).  When the `FILE *` fills up, it will be flushed, probably by some internal function starting with underscore.  That flushing function will call `write`, but that will almost certainly not be visible in the header file.  Bottom line is that this question has no answer in the C programming language (i.e. Oli's answer is correct).  It has a platform specific answer than could vary from one point release to another.

Comment: @prajmus That would be allowed. Everything goes as long as the requirements outlined are fulfilled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void putchar(char c) {
  extern long write(int, const char *, unsigned long);
  (void) write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

Comment: No need for `extern`... And of course, a simpler solution is just `void putchar(char c);` ;)

Comment: He asked for an implementation of `putchar`, so simply declaring the C library version, although it would have worked, would not have met that requirement.

Comment: I agree, this is probably the answer the OP is looking for, although it doesn't tell him/her much...

Comment: @Oli putchar is usually a macro, not a function, I believe

Answer (score 9):

On a POSIX system, such as Linux or OSX, you could use the [`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) system call:

```
/*
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[] = "Hello world\n";

    /* Possible warnings will be encountered here, about implicit declaration
     * of `write` and `strlen`
     */
    write(1, str, strlen(str));
    /* `1` is the standard output file descriptor, a.k.a. `STDOUT_FILENO` */

    return 0;
}
```

On Windows there are similar functions. You probably have to open the console with [`OpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then use [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If you don't want to use any include files, use `1` instead of `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: Would there need to be a header file for declaring `write()`, though?

Comment: You can declare `write` and `strlen` yourself, or your compiler may default to an acceptable declaration (probably with a warning).

Comment: @DWright The `write` function is defined in the `<unistd.h>` header file.

Comment: But I guess, since user specified not `stdio.h`, this still answers the question correctly (inclusion of unistd.h).

Comment: There's `WriteConsole` in Windows as well, by the way.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The point of the exercise was that NO #includes are allowed :-)

Comment: @DWright Nope, NO #include:s allowed -- not even unistd.h :-)

Comment: @knorv It's still work even without the headers, but you will most likely get warnings.

Comment: Ok, now I see that in the sample code.  Perhaps you might put that in the main question body,too.

Comment: For me, this question opens up a whole new line of challenges in life:  Drive to the next city.  **Without using the steering wheel**. :-}

Comment: why leave the compiler make explicit declaration?

Comment: Taking on challenges that are meaninful to learn, yes. Most of us don't need to know how to drive a car without a steering wheel, as if the steering wheel falls off, I will simply press the brake pedal hard, and wait for recovery. It is ABSOLUTELY meaningless to "not use include files" - just as meaningless as trying to (safely) drive a car without a steering wheel.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Do you really think I would have asked the question if I were not interested in the answer? Are you telling me that you find the question meaningless? Thanks for that information!

Comment: I mean,*implicit declaration:

Comment: Not using include files is a completely useless "skill", yes. If you want to learn how things works, try to figure what is IN the header files, and understand how it works. But don't try to work without them - they were created for your convenience, and should be used. When you go to a self-service restaurant and get four plates of food, do you use a tray, or do you carry all four plates balanced on your arms and one on the head? I'd use a tray! Same applies to include files. You are trying to solve a problem that has no meaning in solving!

Comment: @knorv: Everyone here knows the answer to the question.  But the concrete example that you're requesting (for some unknown reason) involves lots of tedious trawling through existing code, which I doubt anyone has the patience for.

Comment: @knorv If you want the implementation of your `putchar` to be _exactly_ as the one in the standard library, then you're on your own. If you just want to make a quick solution that writes a single character to the standard output, there is already enough information in my answer to implement it.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but on a linux machine Oli's example would work, and since Mac's have a very similar OS to Linux, I don't see why this solution wouldn't be right. In my work, I make changes to the Linux operating system (and some related code), and I first started using C as a programming language in 1984-85. If you want to do getchar() in a similart vein, it would be a `read(0, &ch, 1);`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no platform-independent way of doing this.

Of course, on any **specified** platform, you can trivially achieve this by reimplementing/copy-and-pasting the implementation of `stdio.h` (and anything that this in turn relies on).  But this won't be portable.  Nor will it be useful.

Comment: Platform independence was not part of the requirements :-)

Comment: @knorv: Then you should have specified a platform ;)

Comment: @knorv: Yes `putchar` of course works, but its implementation will be different on each platform.  You can take a look at your platform's implementation, and copy it.  That is the crux of my answer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Correct answer == the body of a working putchar(char) function without using any #include:s

Comment: @knorv: No, that's a waste of time ;)  I'm not going to trawl the internet to find the OSX implementation of putchar just to pollute my answer.  Consider it an exercise for the interested reader.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth As the 64:th person to reach 100k rep, I'd assume that you would be able to write a character to stdout using a couple of lines of code max ;-)

Comment: @knorv: I think you're assuming a correlation exists, where in fact there is none...

Answer (score 0):

Since providing a full solutions is probably unsporting,  this is the next best thing...  which is the source-code for [Apple's implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.24/) - which is open source.

I think reducing this to a minimum case is an exercise for the OP.  Apple have even kindly provided an XCode project file.