# Implement write in C without any standard library

Tags: c, stdout, system-calls

I'm trying to implement `printf` in C, without using any standard library, everything works fine if I use the `_write` function from `io.h` header library in windows and write from `unistd` in linux, but I don't really know how to implement that function, any help?

P.S: I've tr to use **asm** to implement syscall as this:

```
int syscall(long number, ...){
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, number);
    int ret;
    __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x80" : "=a"(ret) : "a"(number), "b"(va_arg(args, long)));
    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}
```

And then:

```
syscall(SYS_write, STDOUT, 'a', 1);
```

With SYS_write as 0x05 on windows and 0x04 on linux, and in both stdout as 1

But it doesn't work

EDIT:

```
int syscall3(long number, int a, int b, int c){
    int ret;
    __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x80" : "=a"(ret) : "a"(number), "b"(a), "c"(b), "d"(c) : "memory");
    return ret;
}
```

This is the new version of `syscall`, i think is better still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you want to implement `printf` or `write` ?

Comment: I want to implement printf, but to implement printf i have to implement putchar, and to implement putchar i need write (Maybe the putchar step is an addition, but i'm pretty sure i need anyway the write function

Comment: You're only passing the first of the variadic arguments to `INT 0x80`

Comment: It will be about 5000 lines of code to reimplement printf

Comment: i know that this will be pretty hard, but at least i want to implement even the printf basics, then i'll improve it.

Comment: You pass 2 ints to `syscall` as you've defined it, but you read the argument as `va_arg(args, long)`.

Comment: Better to avoid var-args, and just define syscall1, syscall2, etc. which take the respective number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks, i'll implement syscall3 then, since is the one i need with write.

Comment: I think you should split this into 2 questions, the write one, and the format parsing of printf.

Comment: I dont need any help with the format parsing of printf, i've already written a simple version of it, i only need help for the write, thanks

Comment: I/O is inherently platform specific, just grab the source and copy paste it

Comment: You haven't said what kind of "doesn't work" it's doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a character to standard output in C without using stdio.h or any other library header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296235/how-do-i-write-a-character-to-standard-output-in-c-without-using-stdio-h-or-any)

Comment: You shouldn't be making direct syscalls and interrupts, there is usually no guarantee that they'll stay consistent. Each OS will provide its own specific basic IO functions that are separate from the standard library. On windows it's going to be `WriteConsole`, which is actually a wrapper for `WriteFile` IIRC, which is actually a wrapper for `RtlWriteFile`, which is actually a wrapper for a syscall or an interrupt depending on whether you're using x64 or x86 (and WoW64).

Comment: Replying to hobbs. Sorry, you're right. It just doesn't write anything to stdout

Comment: Thanks Orel and Van Dench. I've already encountered that question while browsing, but it does need to include windows.h. If i try to use -nostdlib, in both of the answers stdlib is needed to include those functions

Comment: You most emphatically do not need stdlib to use Win32 functions. `WriteConsole` is documented as being in `kernel32.dll`, but is actually in `KernelBase.dll` which will eventually point to `ntdll.dll` for the syscalls. Those are Win32 DLL's completely separate from the C++ standard library. The standard library functions for IO are implemented in `api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll` for MSVC.